# List controllers are not supported for Order Item

Tags: visualforce, soql, order, orderitem, list-button

I am trying to create a custom EDIT ALL list button on OrderItem (Order Product) with content source as Visualforce page and am getting below error. I don't want to use standard EDIT ALL button as I want to add some new custom fields to be editable and some fields to be non editable.

> Error: List controllers are not supported for OrderItem

Here is my page:

```
<apex:page standardController="OrderItem"  recordSetVar="EditAllProducts">
    ...
</apex:page>
```

Any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true. Not every object is supported by the StandardSetController class, which is the underlying functionality you tap into when you implement the `recordSetVar` attribute in your page.

You will need to implement this as a custom Apex controller using lists, SOQL and offsets.

There is [a basic example](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/01/soql-offset-in-spring-12.html) of getting this to work in the Salesforce developer blogs with [sample code](https://github.com/sbhanot-sfdc/SOQL-Offset-Sample) in a github repo.

I suggest trying that out, and then coming back with any difficulties you have at that point.